# Making the background view dark, like when the UIAlertView is showing

Tags: ios, uiview, background

Is there any method to do this without drawing a black rect and make it transparent?
Sorry for my poor english I hope you understand what I want.

Comment: That darkener actually is a bitmap that is simply drawn on top of the current key window by iOS. That bitmap and its draw-methods are not available to the public and hence you will simply have to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks I will do it by my self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a view called `backgroundView`

```
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
backgroundView.alpha = 0.8f;
backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Will darken only if the superview (e.g. window) uses a dark color. Also the mentioned effect of UIAlertView shows a slight variance (circle) of darkening -> all of this could be accomplished by adding a layer on top of the view that uses a similar bitmap (radiance alpha sweep).

Comment: This make my view transparent, but I want that the background view become dark and disabled, like when UIAlertView is shown

Comment: Thanks but this change the background of my background view, even if it's a partial solution

Comment: Well you gotta have a background view that will get dark

Comment: I think I get the confusion here: The `backgroundView` in the answer is an extra view for this task, not your existing view.